# Ordering of eigenvectors to maximise trace of diagonalising matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I asked a similar question on the Mathematics stack exchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710701/ordering-of-eigenvectors-to-maximise-trace-of-diagonalising-matrix) without much success, so I thought I'd ask it with a more practical bent here.

Suppose we have a Hermitian matrix $H$ with (for the moment) distinct eigenvalues. Let $\{u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n\}$ be an orthonormal eigenbasis. Most linear algebra packages I know will order these vectors so that the corresponding eigenvalues are in ascending order. However, instead I would like them to be ordered so that the trace of the diagonalising matrix $U$ is maximised; i.e. I would like to find $\max\limits_{\sigma\in S(n)}\sum_j|u_{\sigma(j)j}|$.

Is there any way to avoid simply exhaustively searching the space? Possibly in special cases or to find an approximate solution? For example if $H$ is close to diagonal one would expect $U$ to be close to the identity and thus each $u_j$ to have a unique maximum at different indices; one could then find the location of the maximum for each eigenvector separately and order appropriately, but this breaks down as soon as an eigenvector does not have a unique maximum or two eigenvectors have their maxima at the same index.

Comment: In a more general setting this is called an assignment problem, with standard algorithms available: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem Also equivalent to finding a maximal weighted bipartite matching (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

Comment: Great, thank you. I'd thought there would be some standard algorithms but wasn't sure what to search for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you want to reorder the matrix $U$ is a special case of the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), and it is solved by standard algorithms like the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) implemented in standard libraries (e.g., [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html)). Note that its time complexity is $O(n^3)$, so it won't work on large matrices.

In the assignment problem you are given a cost matrix $C$, and asked to find a mapping $\sigma$ (in your case the matrix is square, so it is a permutation) that maximizes
$$ \sum_i C_{i,\sigma(i)}. $$
So your question is equivalent to this, taking the cost matrix to be $C=|U^\top|$ (transpose because you're reordering matrix rows rather than columns).